How to target on i++ in mixin
I have this method in AnvilScreenHandler:
public void updateResult() {
    ItemStack itemStack = this.input.getStack(0);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    /***/
    for (m = 0; l > 0 && m < itemStack3.getCount(); m++) {
       int n = itemStack2.getDamage() - l;
       itemStack2.setDamage(n);
       i++;
       l = Math.min(itemStack2.getDamage(), itemStack2.getMaxDamage() / 4);
    }
/***/

I want to cancel i++ if itemStack2.getItem() instanceof MyInterface, and I don't understand how to get to this line.
I tried the following, but have not clue:
@Inject(method = "updateResult", at = @At(value = "INVOKE", target = 
    "Lnet/minecraft/item/ItemStack;setDamage(I)V", shift = At.Shift.BY, by = 2))

private void resetRepair(CallbackInfo ci, @Local(ordinal = 1) ItemStack itemStack2,
    @Local(ordinal = 0) LocalRef<Integer> i) {
        if (itemStack2.getItem() instanceof MyInterface) i.set(0);
}

But it produce compile error on i parameter:

@Local does not match any or matched multiple local variables in the target method

Or tried this, but i don't know the target:
@Redirect(method = "updateResult", at = @At(value = "INVOKE", target = "WHAT IS THE TARGET OF i++"))
Or this:
@ModifyConstant(method = "updateResult", constant = @Constant(intValue = 1))
but it even don't show the line in goto.
@ModifyVariable(method = "updateResult", at = @At("STORE"))
It also doesn't show the line in goto and if I log what is a variable, the result was '0' or '15', but not 1.
